# How to de-dupe a List of Objects?

Tags: java, arraylist, deduplication

A `Rec` object has a member variable called `tag` which is a `String`.

If I have a `List` of `Rec`s, how could I de-dupe the list based on the `tag` member variable?

I just need to make sure that the `List` contains only one `Rec` with each `tag` value.

Something like the following, but I'm not sure what's the best algorithm to keep track counts, etc:

```
private List<Rec> deDupe(List<Rec> recs) {

    for(Rec rec : recs) {

         // How to check whether rec.tag exists in another Rec in this List
         // and delete any duplicates from the List before returning it to
         // the calling method?

    }

    return recs;

}
```

Comment: If you are asking how do I remove duplicates from a list, this has been asked many times before; http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+removing+duplicates

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849450/remove-duplicates-from-a-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Store it temporarily in a `HashMap<String,Rec>`.**

Create a `HashMap<String,Rec>`.  Loop through all of your `Rec` objects.  For each one, if the `tag` already exists as a key in the `HashMap`, then compare the two and decide which one to keep.  If not, then put it in.

When you're done, the `HashMap.values()` method will give you all of your unique `Rec` objects.

Comment: Use a LinkedHashMap if you want values() to retain the List ordering.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
private List<Rec> deDupe(List<Rec> recs) {

    Set<String> tags = new HashSet<String>();
    List<Rec> result = new ArrayList<Rec>();

    for(Rec rec : recs) {
        if(!tags.contains(rec.tags) {
            result.add(rec);
            tags.add(rec.tag);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This checks each `Rec` against a `Set` of tags.  If the set contains the tag already, it is a duplicate and we skip it.  Otherwise we add the `Rec` to our result and add the tag to the set.

Comment: you can make it simpler by using the return value of Set.add: if (tags.add(rec.tags)) result.add(rec)

Comment: Yes.  This is what `Set` is for ... having a collection of distinct objects.

Answer (score 1):

This becomes easier if `Rec` is `.equals` based on its `tag` value. Then you could write something like:

```
private List<Rec> deDupe( List<Rec> recs )
{
    List<Rec> retList = new ArrayList<Rec>( recs.size() );
    for ( Rec rec : recs )
    {
        if (!retList.contains(rec))
        {
            retList.add(rec);
        }
    }
    return retList;
 }
```

Comment: Couldn't you use Set.addAll(recs)?

Comment: @Rich - I tried using a HashSet but I was able to add multiple objects with different `tag` values so the uniqueness of the set seems to be based on some other attribute of the `Rec` object but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @Rich: Yes, that would work (probably better than my submission)

Comment: @Reese: Is there any potential danger of overriding the `equals` method to base it on the `tag` value?

Comment: @Daniel K: Unless you have some other semantic definition for equals that is used you *most definitely should* provide a semantic meaning for .equals

Comment: @Daniel K: the HashSet relies on correct overriding of equals and hashCode - that will be why it didn't work before

Answer (score 0):

I would do that with the google collections. You can use the filter function, with a predicate that remember previous tags, and filters out Rec's with tag that has been there before.
Something like this:

```
private Iterable<Rec> deDupe(List<Rec> recs) 
{
    Predicate<Rec> filterDuplicatesByTagPredicate = new FilterDuplicatesByTagPredicate();
    return Iterables.filter(recs, filterDuplicatesByTagPredicate);
}

private static class FilterDuplicatesByTagPredicate implements Predicate<Rec>
{
    private Set<String> existingTags = Sets.newHashSet();

    @Override
    public boolean apply(Rec input)
    {
        String tag = input.getTag();
        return existingTags.add(tag);
    }
}
```

I slightly changed the method to return Iterable instead of List, but ofcourse you change that if that's important.

Comment: The javadoc for Predicate strongly advises against having predicates where apply() has any observable side effect.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036326/google-collections-distinct-predicate/4036416#4036416

Comment: Can you please explain why? What's the pitfall here?

Comment: Side effects make code harder to understand, particularly when they're hidden in unexpected places. The standard expectation for a `Predicate` is that it is a fixed logical predicate for which each element that is given to it is evaluated in the same way. With this predicate, the criteria for evaluation changes continually during the course of a single call to `filter`. The predicate is, of course, not reusable either... using it again would cause it to filter out every element of the original list. This violates expectations.. a `Map` is a more appropriate solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about shuffling the data around (i.e you have a small list of small objects), you can do this:

```
private List<T> deDupe(List<T> thisListHasDupes){
    Set<T> tempSet = new HashSet<T>();
    for(T t:thisListHasDupes){
        tempSet.add(t);
    }
    List<T> deDupedList = new ArrayList<T>();
    deDupedList.addAll(tempSet);
    return deDupedList;
}
```

Remember that implmenations of Set are going to want a consistent and valid equals operator.  So if you have a custom object make sure that's taken care of.